# Post request doesn't receive data from autocomplete (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I apaologize in advance if not enough info will be given, I'm just a novice, but i will try to explain it the best I can.
In short, the data from ajax is not sent back to the "AutoComplete" request in  the controller. I have a input form field that is directly connected to the autocomplete function, the "url" is specified and all the components i can think of. I think the problem is in the "data" part of the code, but I'm not quite sure. When i hardcode the incoming string value to a letter that one of the names in my database contains, then it works fine (discluding the possibility of the controller not working properly). Code below.

**Home controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TestView() 
{
     return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix) 
{
    var customers = (from customer in _context.Customers where customer.Name.StartsWith(prefix) select new {
    label = customer.Name, val = customer.CustomerId})
    .ToList();

     return Json(customers);

}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestView(string CustomerName, string CustomerId) 
{
    ViewBag.Message = "CustomerName: " + CustomerName + " CustomerId: " + CustomerId;
    return View();
}
```

**TestView.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}", @* also tryed == > data: { prefix: request.term }*@
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },

                        error: function(response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function(response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function(e, i) {
                    $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TestView", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="text" id="txtCustomer" name="CustomerName"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfCustomer" name="CustomerId" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        <br />
        <br />
        @ViewBag.Message
    }
</body>
```

Hope I managed to explain enough and sorry if my terminology is not the best. Thank you!

Comment: It hits the endpoint when you hard code the data in jquery?

Comment: Instead of this `data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}"` please try this line: `data: {"prefix": request.term }` and if that does not work, please try this one: `data: JSON.stringify({"prefix": request.term })`

Comment: Hi! Actually no, I tried to put let's say `"L"` instead of the `request.term` (if that makes sense) in all of the above cases and still it doesn't send it back. Also tried to create a local layout just so I'm sure that it's not the json from the global layout interfering but still nothing. And i also tried your suggestions as you wrote them, but prefix is still "null". The only time it's working is when I hardcore it in the controller. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also when i add the `console.log(this.data)` action under `success: function (data)`, I get back what i entered in the console (if that helps in any way).